# Django & Celery & Pexpect - how to communicate with GDB

Tags: python, django, gdb, celery, pexpect

I'm currently writing an app, where user can run code in asm language and debug it. On the server side I want to run user's code in gdb and wait for commands like 'step', 'continue' etc. Now I'm using pexpect for start gdb and send initial commands to it.

```
child = pexpect.spawn('gdb -q ' + exe_file_path)
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout
child.expect('(gdb)')
child.sendline('b 1')
child.expect('(gdb)')
child.sendline('run')
child.expect('(gdb)')
```

Now I have a problem. I want to wait for user action. For example if he press "Step" button, I want to send to created process these commands:

```
child.sendline('step')
child.expect('(gdb)')
child.sendline('info registers')
child.expect('(gdb)')
```

But here I have a problem, because "child" process was ended, a now child variable is referenced before assignment. How to force Django, to remember created process, and send commands to it? I trying to use Celery and first step with creation of process was successfull, but I don't know how to send next commands to this process. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't know about most Django or Celery -- but you should use the gdb MI mode and not the ordinary CLI.  Or, send code back and forth to gdb using its Python interface.  Relying on the CLI like this is definitely not a good approach.